# What is the shadow element simply for HTML?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, shadow-dom

the following is sample js for shadow element

```
    class SliderImages extends window.HTMLDivElement {
      constructor (...args) {
        const self = super(...args)
        self.init()
        return self
      }

      init () {
        this.$ = $(this)
        this.props = this.getInitialProps()
        this.resolveElements()
      }

      getInitialProps () {
        let data = {}
        try {
          data = JSON.parse($('script[type="application/json"]', this).text())
        } catch (e) {}
        return data
      }

      resolveElements () {
        this.$slider = $('[data-slider]', this)
        this.$buttonNext = $('[data-slider-button="next"]', this)
        this.$buttonPrev = $('[data-slider-button="prev"]', this)
      }

      connectedCallback () {
        this.initSlider()
      }

      initSlider () {
        const { options } = this.props
        const config = {
          navigation: {
            nextEl: this.$buttonNext,
            prevEl: this.$buttonPrev
          },
          a11y: options.a11y
        }
        if (options.autoplay && options.autoplaySpeed) {
          config.autoplay = {
            delay: options.autoplaySpeed
          }
        }
        this.slider = new Swiper(this.$slider, config)
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define('flynt-slider-images', SliderImages, { extends: 'div' })
```

I am not clear why shadow element is using and what is the advantage of using them. and when I am going to use the shadow element, what the special JS library is needed?
if anyone please explain me simply and clearly, I am thankful.

Comment: I don't see any Shadow DOM in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Custom Elements** permit you to create, reuse and distribute your own web components without native Javascript. No need for a 3rd party framework.

Read that presentation from Google: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

---

**Shadow DOM** permits to isolate the CSS style of your web components, to control their rendering and to avoid unwanted side effects when displayed in unmanaged webpages.

Read that introduction from Google: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom